# how to extract a value from changing string in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I want to extract a value from a string(which constantly changes) for further procesing.

The string is

```
TPSM seed 4339CD65   pass 1  x 0 x 1  errors 0 pid 179947 rulefilecycle 0
TPSM seed 5339CD60   pass 1  x 9 x 2  errors 0 pid 179947 rulefilecycle 0
TPSM seed 2339CD61   pass 1  x 101 x 5  errors 0 pid 179947 rulefilecycle 0
TPSM seed 5339CD65   pass 1  x 19 x 6  errors 0 pid 179947 rulefilecycle 0
TPSM seed 9339CD65   pass 1  x 100 x 7  errors 0 pid 179947 rulefilecycle 0
```

I want to extract the values after **pass** of the form 1 x a x **n** , where i am interested in the value of 'n' .
I was trying using the substr() in perl but since the numbers keep changing i can't write some thing like **substr($string,37,1)**.

How could I achieve this without substr() in some regex way?

Answer (score 5):

How about:

```
my ($n) = $string =~ /pass\s+\d+\s+x\s+\d+\s+x\s+(\d+)/;
```

**Explanation:**

```
/         : Regex delimiter
pass      : literally pass
\s+\d+\s+ : 1 or more spaces, 1 or more digits, 1 or more spaces (ie. the first number)
x         : literally x
\s+\d+\s+ : 1 or more spaces, 1 or more digits, 1 or more spaces (ie. the second number)
x         : literally x
\s+       : 1 or more spaces
(\d+)     : 1 or more digits, captured in group 1 (ie. the third number)
/         : regex delimiter
```

If `$string` is matched by the regex, the third number is captured in group 1, then the value in this group is used to populate the variable `$n`.

As said in comments, it can be simplified in:

```
my ($n) = $string =~ /pass(?:\s+\d+\s+x){2}\s+(\d+)/;
```

Where `(?:...)` is a non capture group.

Comment: This works, i need to figure out what is this command, i mean it seems to be regex, tq

Comment: can simplify to `/pass(?:\s+\d+\s+x){2}\s+(\d+)/` to take adv of repeating pattern

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
while(<DATA>)
{
    printf "%s\n", ($_=~m/\s*x\s*(\d+)\s*errors\s0/i)[0];
}


__DATA__
TPSM seed 4339CD65   pass 1  x 0 x 1  errors 0 pid 179947 rulefilecycle 0
TPSM seed 5339CD60   pass 1  x 9 x 2  errors 0 pid 179947 rulefilecycle 0
TPSM seed 2339CD61   pass 1  x 101 x 5  errors 0 pid 179947 rulefilecycle 0
TPSM seed 5339CD65   pass 1  x 19 x 6  errors 0 pid 179947 rulefilecycle 0
TPSM seed 9339CD65   pass 1  x 100 x 7  errors 0 pid 179947 rulefilecycle 0
```

Comment: `$_ =~` is redundant in your example - that's the default anyway. You could write instead: `print +(m/\s*x\s*(\d+)\s*errors\s0/i)[0],"\n";`

Comment: @Sobrique: Fine. Noted on this one.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `split`:

By default, `split` will split on `/\s+/`, and you can then access the desired element as you would for an array:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw / say /;

while(<DATA>){
    chomp;
    my $num = (split)[8];
    say $num;
}
```